# bootstrap messed up form

Tags: html, css

[Screenshot of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzwBD.png)

I'm having trouble with Bootstrap. I have a form with three textboxes. The top textbox, email, is not aligned with the rest of the textboxes. I've included the HTML:

```html
<form role="form" action="register.php" method="POST" form-horizontal novalidate>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="email"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"  placeholder="Enter Email">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <span></span>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">

        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="username"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password ">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Register</button>
    </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using form class only one time not again & again and if you want text like "email" then use `<label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="email">Email</label>` otherwise no use of it and use only 12 column as [col-sm-2] for label and for input [col-sm-10] or you can use as [col-sm-4] or [col-sm-8]

```html
<form role="form" action="register.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal novalidate">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"  placeholder="Enter Email">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password ">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Register</button>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                </form>
```

Comment: thanks it worked do you know how i can make some space between them? like under each form some space to output error msg?

Comment: in bootstrap style for .form-group {margin-bottom: 15px;} is it not mention there or you can add

Answer (score 0):

You have missplaced few css class,replace your form with following code, will solve your problem:

```
<form role="form" action="register.php" method="POST" class='form-horizontal novalidate'  role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label> 
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email"> 
    </div> 
</div> 
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">UserName</label> 
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter User Name"> 
    </div> 
</div> 
<div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label> 
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password"> </div> 
    </div> 
</div>  
<div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Register</button>
    </div> 
</div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong html code. Replace your form with following code, will solve your problem:

```
    <form role="form" action="register.php" method="POST" form-horizontal novalidate>

 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label> 
      <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"  placeholder="Enter Email">
      </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Name</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password ">
     </div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Register</button>
       </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is my jsfiddle code : https://jsfiddle.net/0oeabj76/1/